# Trifecta odds - exact odds

Tags: probability

I understand the probability of trifectas, however, how is the probability affected by the price of each runner - eg.  6 runners = 120 combinations. Rather than having same amount on each combination, if runner A was 2.50 and runner B was 5.00 and Runner C was 6.50 what would be the trifecta price of A-B-C compared with C-B-A?